# How to connect OV7670 cam to Raspberry Pi Pico

Tags: camera, pi-pico

I have a raspberry pi pico and OV7670 cam. I want to connect them and get a camera output as a video, So I can use image recognition to identify objects (tennis balls) to collect them using a setup with motor drive+motor setup. Please help with your ideas and reference links. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the RPI pico C sdk to write firmware code for reading image data pins of off ov7670.
This explains how to setup the PCIO C SDK https://datasheets.raspberrypi.com/pico/getting-started-with-pico.pdf

Look at the ov7670 schematic here to figure out the ov7670 hookup/wiring to PICO http://web.mit.edu/6.111/www/f2016/tools/OV7670_2006.pdf

You'd realize that PICO's GPIO sampling rate is slower than ov7670 data rate. You might be able to do something to compensate for the data rate mismatch, maybe only read a few selective lines every frame. Might not work for video, but maybe stills, or video in grayscale on a lower resolution might work.

Let me know if you need more help!

Comment: I find out that pico can't read with ov7670 efficiently. So I barrow pi to do this work. Its a raspberry Pi 3 B model. The thing is I can't install  opencv in the board. When I tried to download all package its struck on middle and when I try to download zip. its very slow and download for 13 to 15mb then Its retiring to download. How should resolve this. can you help me.

Comment: YOCTO can be used for making custom Linux builds. Yocto uses meta layers making build builds for different targets / systems and adding different packages. There is is a meta layer for Raspberry Pi, you can look at it here https://github.com/agherzan/meta-raspberrypi Learn a little about YOCTO, and then use meta-rapberrypi to add opengl etc and other packages of your liking to your build.

Answer (score 0):

Wiring tutorial in this link that shows how to wire the camera module to a pi pico and it provides a python code example for several camera models including ov7670:

https://learn.adafruit.com/capturing-camera-images-with-circuitpython/raspberry-pi-pico-wiring

Two (untested) c++ repositories that can be used as drivers/code samples:

https://github.com/usedbytes/camera-pico-ov7670

https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_OV7670/tree/pb-rp2040

You will have to dig into the code of whichever repository you choose in order to figure out or modify the pin connections and have it match the actual wiring.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/129507)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).